# Application Health Check with HTTPS only

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

If I add the following health check in the ELB: /health 
(where /health returns an http 200 and a Response payload "ok") then the environment is green. 
If I change the health check to HTTPS:443/health Then the environment becomes red and all the responses become 503. 
The certificate that I'm using is an ACM one. 
The security group of the BE app includes the port 443. 
The /health works fine by itself. 
I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Does your application server (the instance, not the balancer) actually speak HTTPS on port 443?  Because that's what the health check is checking -- the back-end, not the balancer... and you didn't mention anything in your description about the additional steps needed to make that work.

Comment: I just tried to connect to a particular EC2 instance using its public IP. It  works with http but not with https. So it appears that the application server does not speak HTTPS on port 443. I'll look into it and come back with feedback.